# What is the difference between .// and // when they are used in the middle of the xpath?

Tags: xpath, htmlunit

What is the difference between using

```
htmlElement.getByXPath("//section")
```

and

```
htmlElement.getByXPath(".//section")
```

Do they both mean that the section element is searched only inside htmlElement? (and not in the entire xml starting at dom root)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first `//section` will retrieve all `<section>` elements wherever they are in your document, and independently of the context.

The second `.//section` will take into account the element you are currently located in (typically in an XSL transformation), so that it will retrieve only the `<section>` in the node represented by the `htmlElement` variable. I don't know htmlunit, but in XPath an equivalent would be `descendant::section`.

Comment: But div//section will not search all section elements anywhere inside the document, it will search only inside the div, right?

Comment: @GabrielaVisinari yes. A slash (or double-slash) at the _start_ of a path makes it absolute, starting from the root, a slash anywhere else is taken as relative to the thing to the left of the slash (`.`, `div`, or whatever).

Comment: @Ian Roberts then the two statements in the original question aren't equivalent?

Comment: @GabrielaVisinari correct, and this is exactly what potame's answer says.